# parsing humanized dates in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I allow users to create their own date filters. For example, they can create a date filter called 'last week', 'next week', 'yesterday', 'today', 'tomorrow', 'last 7 days', 'next 30 days', etc. Obviously, the strings and not the actual dates are stored in the database, since it is relative: next week can be a different date depending on when the query is run.

My question is should I write my own parser e.g. MyDateWrapper.parse('last week')? Or does ruby have the ability to handle humanized date strings out of the box?

Comment: Use the Chronic parser library, I don't recall the name off the top of my head.

Comment: @DaveNewton I tested the gem out. It seems to do pretty well. However, it doesn't work with 'last 7 days', 'last 6 days', 'next 25 days', etc. So I am going to use the gem, but write a wrapper ontop of it for unique situations.

Comment: @Donato The name is escaping me, but I am fairly confident there is a gem similar to chronic meant for time ranges.  Worth spending a little time searching for it before building one.

Comment: https://github.com/jrobertson/chronic_between maybe

Comment: https://github.com/yb66/tickle